# Outlook Html mailer bad rendering

Tags: html, styles, html-email, frontend

I wrote a mailer for a campaign.On all mail clients it looked as the design, however on outlook it looked nasty.i got some elements wrapped by

tag that i didn't put with class .MsoNormal, I want to rebuild the mailer in a way that i don't get such bad result with Microsoft outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You will always find rendering differences on email clients when using HTML.
It is hard to tell exactly what is happening on your campaign if you don't post the code or the specific issue.

What I would suggest is

- Use http://htmlemailboilerplate.com
- Have a look at campaign monitor email css guide http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
- Try to make things simpler

We can probably help you if you post the specific code problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your header style section:

```
p.MsoNormal {margin: 0px}
```

As suggested above, use the html boilerplate when creating html email. Here is a compressed version that I use in all emails. Consider it the normalize script for html email.

```
<style type="text/css">
/* RESET */
  html {width: 100%;} body {width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; word-wrap:normal;}
  /* Hotmail */
  .ReadMsgBody, .ExternalClass {width:100%; display:block !important;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {color: black !important;} h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {color: blue !important;}
  h1 a:active, h2 a:active,  h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active { color: red !important; } h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited,  h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
  /* Outlook */
  table td {border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} #outlook a {padding:0;} #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;} p.MsoNormal {margin: 0px}
  /* Yahoo */
  p {margin: 1em 0;}
  /* Images */
  img {outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} a img {border:none;} .image_fix {display:block;}
  /* Override phone number link styling */
  a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] { text-decoration: none; color: black; pointer-events: none; cursor: default; }
/* /RESET */
</style>
```